# Multiple zip codes from Geocoding Service in Angular ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have a ui-select which when you enter a zip code into, it provides a list of addresses (zip code, city, country) that you can choose, and when you choose one, it adds it into the ui-select input box. I have the ui-select setup as multiple.

The zip codes come from an Angular Geocoding service, where you just call to the route with params (being the zip code and the country, which is always USA), and it return back an id, and a text suggestion of the location, which is the zip code, city, and country separated by commas

My question is this, when I add the addresses from the dropdown to the ui-select input box, how do I actually access those values from the controller.

Here is my ui-select code:

```
<ui-select ng-model="area.location" multiple theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Enter a postal code..." ng-model="code">{{$item.text}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="address in addresses | filter: $select.search" refresh="getSearchLocation($select.search)" refresh-delay="0">
            <div ng-bind-html="address.text | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

The `getSeachLocation($select.search)` function is what retrieves the zip code info.

I hope this is enough code; if I need to add more, let me know.

I just cannot seem to get access to whatever values I add to the ui-select in the controller.

Hope this all made sense, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide sample data to work with? if possible a fiddle with the issue?

Comment: I think that would be a huge amount of code, since this is for my app at work, and there are so many dependencies and things piggy backing off each other. What I am mainly looking for is how to access the ui-select values in the controller.

I can try and make a fiddle, but that may take a very long time...

Comment: I understand! No Problem!

Comment: Doesn't `$scope.area.location` already contain what you need?

Comment: That's what I would think too, but it does not - `$scope.area.location` is just an empty array for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

You can access these at any time after selection in the controller using the ui-select's ng-model which is an array of your values/structures you assigned for ui-select-choices.

For examples, I access my selected items like `var selected = $scope.placesModel.selected[n]` (it's an array for multiple selects, remember). The value at that index is whatever you assigned to choices. In my case it's a simple json object so I can access the object properties like `selected.id`.